# How do I run a Flash exe file within a Window/Form in a VB.Net Project?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, flash

How do I run a Flash exe file within a Window/Form in a VB.Net Project?
I do not have the SWF file so will have to use the exe file I have.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can extract the swf file from the exe flash projector?
There are lots af utils that can do that, like this [one](http://www.northcode.com/blog.php/2007/08/02/Extract-SWF-files-from-Flash-Executables).

Answer (score 0):

add flash executable file to your project as embedded resource,
during the run time extract to temp folder run the project. at form closing delete the temp older flash executable file.

hope it helps.